# Pagination next page refreshes same data

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to do pagination and it's working fine. but i'm having little problem.

```
$selectedCategory = Course::where('course_category_id', $category->id)
                            ->StatusOn()
                            ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
                            ->paginate(9);
```

when i added orderBy and when i'm clicking on next page it's getting same courses that was in first page and it's orderBy fault. But i need orderBy so what can i do?

Comment: do you have ```page=2``` GET parameter  when clicking on second page?

Comment: Yes i'm having {!! $selectedCategory->links() !!} and it's getting page 2 parameters. and without orderBy it's working perfect.

Comment: are the results on all page the same? or just some results partly occurs again?

Comment: No they are not same. some results partly occurs again.

Comment: you can install laravel debugbar and look the query what's happen under the hood and debug it.

Comment: I really don't know how to use debugbar correctly. But i'm getting this in debugbar select * from `courses` where `course_category_id` = 21 and `status` = '1' and `created_at` is not null and `courses`.`deleted_at` is null order by `created_at` desc limit 18 offset 0

Answer (score 0):

You are using offset pagination, some results can occur again, so you can try [cursor](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/pagination#cursor-pagination) pagination. [read the difference between offset and cursor pagination](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/pagination#cursor-vs-offset-pagination)

Comment: I'm new in this not really know how to use it... But it's mysql syntax  select * from users order by id asc limit 15 offset 15;
 ?

Comment: Really don't understand how to do it... but thanks for response )

Comment: No, ```select * from users where id > ? order by id limit 15```

Comment: I don't know how to use mysql syntax and don't having time to learn it. ) so i'm searching now for different way to fix this problem. but if i will not found different why then i must use this...

Answer (score 0):

When i was clicking on next page Some results partly occurred again.
but then i added to my code ->orderBy('id') and now it's working perfect.

```
$selectedCategory = Course::where('course_category_id', $category->id)->StatusOn()->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->orderBy('id')->paginate(18);
```

Thanks all for response  )

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Is ```orderBy('created_at', 'desc')``` redundantin your query builder chain?

Comment: No it's need  orderBy('created_at', 'desc') but it's also need orderBy('id')